# sysocmgr to pkgmgr in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using the following code to auto-install the Microsoft's Message Queuing service under Windows XP:

```
;@echo off
;sysocmgr.exe /i:sysoc.inf /u:MSMQsetup.bat
;GOTO Finished

[Components]
msmq_Core = ON

msmq_LocalStorage = ON

msmq_ADIntegrated = ON

msmq_TriggersService = ON

msmq_HTTPSupport = OFF

msmq_RoutingSupport = OFF

msmq_MQDSService = OFF

;:Finished
```

And it works fine under XP, but in Windows Vista, 7 or 8 this command does not exist anymore. The new "command" is called pkgmgr.exe in this systems and DISM.exe on Windows 8.1/2012 and I really don't know how to make them work to do the same thing (auto-install the Microsoft's Message Queuing).

> EDIT:
>
> The way to do it with Dism is:
>
> dism /Online /NoRestart /English /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:MSMQ-Container /FeatureName:MSMQ-Server

> Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't help but Windows 8.1 now has `DISM.exe` instead of pkgmgr.exe

Comment: this can help to improve the question, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pkgmgr /iu:MSMQ-Container;MSMQ-Server